# PySpark Tabula-Py Read_PDF (ERROR: No module named 'org.apache.commons')

Tags: pandas, azure, pyspark, tabula, tabula-py

I've been runnning a pipeline in Azure for 4 months and it suddenly broke last night. I have the following code:

```
!pip install tabula-py
from tabula.io import read_pdf
import tabula
df = tabula.io.read_pdf(BytesIO(pdf_content), pandas_options={'header': None}, pages=3, stream=True)[0]
```

I got this error all of a sudden now:

```
~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tabula/io.py in __init__(self, java_options, silent)
     92 
     93         from java import lang
---> 94         from org.apache.commons import cli
     95         from technology import tabula
     96 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org.apache.commons'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

the same happened to me today in a databricks environment after tabula was running smoothly for 6 months. My hotfix was to pip install the version 2.7.0 as I suppose the error is evoked by the most current version 2.8.1 which was published today.

Comment: It didn't work for me for some reason. I thought it would do the trick. 
!pip install tabula-py==2.7.0. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: It ended up working for me, I just had to create a new notebook and copy my code over. It must have been some cached version issue with the old notebook.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

tabula-py author is here.

I released v2.8.2 adding fallback to subprocess if jpype has importing issue.
https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/2.8.2/

Answer (score 0):

Installing version 2.7.0 with the command pip install tabula-py==2.7.0 worked for me as well.